# Expanding a PS an attribute for use on the same object

Tags: powershell

I'm working in PowerShell and I have a small thing that's driving me crazy. I'm pretty sure it's by design, however I don't have an understanding of why or what the correct syntax is.

For example I have the following which works.

```
get-adcomputer XXX-002 | foreach-object {
    $description = $_.Description
    Set-ADcomputer $_ -Location $description
}
```

I'd rather not need to define another variable for an attribute already set, so I'd like the following to work:

```
get-adcomputer XXX-002 | foreach-object {
    Set-ADcomputer $_ -Location $_.Description
}
```

I was thinking that this just needed a subexpression to be sure it evaluated so I tried this.

```
get-adcomputer XXX-002 | foreach-object {
    Set-ADcomputer $_ -Location $($_.Description) 
}
```

Neither of these populate my fields correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Neither of these populate my fields correctly" - does it populate them incorrectly then?

Comment: Somehow I think the answer to this is going to be related to the weirdness of the AD objects and their dynamic properties, but I'm surprised the subexpression didn't work. I also want to know, what is being set in the examples that don't work?

Comment: @briantist agreed. `"$($_.Description)"` or `$_.Location = $_.Description; Set-ADComputer -Instance $_` might work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
get-adcomputer XXX-002 | foreach-object {
    Set-ADcomputer $_ -Location ($_).Description 
}
```